Does Fischer decomposition holds also for power series?
Fischer proved that given any polynomial $q$, then every homogeneous polynomial $P_k$ of degree $k$, can be uniquely decomposed as
$$
P_k(x)=Q_k(x)+q(x)R(x),
$$
where $Q_k$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $k$ that satisfies the equation
$$
q(D)Q_k(x)=0,
$$
where $q$ acts on $D$ by the identification of $x_i\leftrightarrow\partial_i$. (For example, if $q(x)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$, then the Fischer decomposition for $q$ coincides with the classical harmonic decomposition, as $q(D)=\Delta$.) Then, by linearity the decomposition extend to any polynomial.
My question is the following: does the Fischer decomposition holds also for power series and not only for polynomials?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

How can a power series be homogeneous?

You don't need homogeneity, as the decomposition is linear. I assumed the polynomial homogeneous only to show the explicit decomposition.
